# How to correct this? Windows Automation in notepad use swapy. Python

Tags: python

```
from pywinauto.application import Application


import keyboard

app = Application().start("notepad.exe")

notepad = app.Notepad
write file
app.notepad.Edit.type_keys(No No No No No No No No No No No No No!, 
with_spaces = True)

notepad.Wait(ready)
menu_item = notepad.MenuItem(uF&ormat->&Word Wrap)
menu_item.Click()

menu_item = notepad.MenuItem(uF&ormat->&Font...)
menu_item.Click()

keyboard.hook_key({DOWN})
keyboard.hook_key({ENTER})
```

from pyautogui import hotkey
hotkey(down)
hotkey(enter)
I want to use the second way: keyboard.hook_key({DOWN})

Comment: This question is really unclear. What do you want to achieve? what have you tried to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pyautogui import hotkey

# import keyboard

app = Application().start("notepad.exe")

notepad = app.Notepad
# write file
app.notepad.Edit.type_keys("No No No No No No No No No No No No No!", with_spaces = True)

notepad.Wait('ready')
menu_item = notepad.MenuItem(u'F&ormat->&Word Wrap')
menu_item.Click()

menu_item = notepad.MenuItem(u'F&ormat->&Font...')
menu_item.Click()

# keyboard.hook_key("{DOWN}")
# keyboard.hook_key("{ENTER}")
hotkey('down')
hotkey('enter')
```